# Django Order By on Reverse Foreign Key value drops items without relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

#### Context

I am trying to sort a list of objects based on the value of a reverse foreign key relationship.
I have partial solution, but filter used creates an inner join that drops objects without the relationship.

The outcome I want to create sorted queryset with all objects, threating "null" reverse relationships as if the related value was null.

#### Models

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Subject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Grade(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey("Student", related_name="grades", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey("Subject", related_name="grades", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

**Fixtures**

```
+------+------------------------+
| name | subject  | grade_value |
+------+----------+-------------+
| beth | math     | 100         |
| beth | history  | 100         |
| mark | math     | 90          |
| mark | history  | 90          |
| mike | history  | 80          |
+------+----------+-------------+
```

#### Desired Outcome

When sorting students by their **"history"** grade, I want to get `[ beth (100), mark (90), mike (80) ]`

Now let's say `mark` was sick at home and missed the `math` exam.

When sorting students by their **"math"** grade, I want to get `[ beth (100), mark (90), mike (null) ]`

Instead, for the sorted by math grade returns `[ beth (100), mark (90) ]`.

#### Attempted Solution

I know I could fetch all and rejoin results, but I looking for an efficient ORM queryset solution if possible.

```py
>>> Student.objects.filter(grades__subject__title="history").order_by("grades__value")
<Student: Beth>, <Student: Mark>, <Student: Mike>

>>> Student.objects.filter(grades__subject__title="math").order_by("grades__value")
<Student: Beth>, <Student: Mark>
```

#### Update

I tried using a union as suggested but I am not sure why it causes related look up to fail:

```
>>> Student.objects.filter(grades__subject__title="math")\
     .union(Student.objects.all())\
     .order_by("grades__value")

...
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'value' into field. Choices are: grades, id, name
```

#### Solution

Validation below using solution by @schillingt.

```
grades = Grade.objects.filter(
    student_id=OuterRef('id'), subject__title="math"
)
students = Student.objects.annotate(
    subject_grade=Subquery(grades.values('value')[:1])
)
```

```
>>> [f"{s.name}: {s.subject_grade}" for s in students.order_by("subject_grade")]
['mike: None', 'mark: 90', 'beth: 100']
>>>
>>> [f"{s.name}: {s.subject_grade}" for s in students.order_by("-subject_grade")]
['beth: 100', 'mark: 90', 'mike: None']
>>>
```

Comment: The issue is not the `order_by` it is the `filter(grades__subject__title="math")`

Comment: You could use a union to concatenate the students that don't have a related grade to the end of the results? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#union

Comment: @IainShelvington 
"The issue is not the order_by it is the filter" I understand that, but I need to filter before sorting otherwise you sort by all value not only selected subjects. I will update the question to clarify

Comment: @IainShelvington I had tried a union but it takes the query out of order. I will update to reflect that

Comment: You're missing an underscore in your order_by

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong snipped. for some reason order by after union causes related lookup to fail. btw, thank you for your help! all excellent questions and suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a [Subquery expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) in an annotation.

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef
subject = "math"
grades = Grade.objects.filter(
    student_id=OuterRef('id'),
    subject__title=subject,
).order_by('value')
students = Student.objects.annotate(
    annotated_grade=Subquery(grades.values('value')[:1]),
)
print(students.first().annotated_grade) # The first student's highest math grade.
```

Comment: small typo correction: `grades.value` should be `grades.values`